# Using a VBA script to make flat files - Remove blank rows and handle more volumes?

Tags: excel, vba, text, flat-file

Completely new to VBA, and here for that matter. I'm trying to write a script for converting data in an Excel spreadsheet to a flat file (.txt) for loading into an ERP.

I've got as far as piecing together the below script, but have two problems that I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction for resolving.

1. The flat file has blank rows at the bottom of the data.
2. The script can't seem to handle large volumes. I'm getting overflow errors at around the 30,000 row mark.

Here's what I've got so far, apologies if it's messy:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    ' Turns all the numbers and stuff into a flat file!!!

    ' Defines things.
    Dim myPRFile As String
    Dim TextFile As Integer
    Dim FileContent As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cellValue As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    ' Defines the file to use and the part of the spreadsheet to copy from.
    myPRFile = "C:\Users\my.folder\Documents\Docs\Logics\flat.txt"
    Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Select
    Set rng = Selection
    
    ' Loops through the data puts it in the text file.
    Open myPRFile For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
    If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
        Print #1, cellValue
    Else
        Print #1, cellValue; "|";
    End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Close #1
    
    ' Takes the spaces out of the file.
    TextFile = FreeFile
    
    Open myPRFile For Input As TextFile
    FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
    Close TextFile
    
    FileContent = Replace(FileContent, " ", "")
    
    Open myPRFile For Output As TextFile
    Print #TextFile, FileContent
    Close TextFile
    
    ' Opens the finished product.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim sfile As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("shell.application")
    sfile = "C:\Users\my.folder\Documents\Docs\Logics\flat.txt"
    fso.Open (sfile)

End Sub
```

It's perfectly useful as is, but I'd love to crack these last couple of things if possible.

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/textfiles.html)?

Comment: I hadn't, despite searching everywhere. Thank you @SiddharthRout, I'll have a read.

Comment: `Integer` maxes out around 32,000 - there's no reason not to use `Long` (and plenty of reasons not to use `Integer`)

Comment: Instead of using `CurrentRegion`, I would suggest using [identifying the last row](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm).